# How to set image's height as much as the text content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In my page I show posts from feeds. A post-preview has an image and the content. The width of the image is fixed at 150px but I want the image to have height equal to content's height. A post-preview content may have less than 450 chars, that means that the height of it will be smaller that other posts.

Is this possible using jQuery?

This is my code:

```
<div id="post">

<div id="image">
<?php 
$imgpath="timthumb.php?src=THE-IMAGE.PNG&h=91&w=150"; } ?>
<img border="0" src="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>"></img>
</div>

<div id="thepost2">
<?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($entry->description), 0, 450, "UTF-8"); ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HTML
    <div id="uniqueid" class="autoheight">
        <img />
    </div>

    $('.autoheight img').css({height: $('#thepost2').height(), width:'150 px'});
```

If you will not specify the width it will set the width equal to height as well. So you will be specifying width appropriately as your needs. It may change the aspect ratio of the image and it might not look good.

Comment: I have multiple `<div id="image">` How can I make it work to all ?

Comment: You can't have multiple `<div id="image">` in same page. You can give your div a class and it will apply this for all.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle for your better understanding http://jsfiddle.net/BLUzJ/14/

Comment: I guess my question was not clear enough, because I have a fixed height... All what is needed is in the fiddle

Comment: what's the problem here. I guess image height is equal to post height. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes but from css, my content height is always the same